# forcing a form field to be comma separated string

Tags: html, angularjs, forms, validation, csv

I am developing a form using HTML and angularjs. How do I ensure that a field is a comma separated list of values? Is it even a good idea from a security perspective? If not, are there any alternatives (other than uploading a CSV file)

Thanks

Comment: Are you expecting that users would paste in CSV data rather than uploading?

Comment: What type of field is it?  Is it a text input, or a select?  Could you please add some more details?

Comment: Additionally, are you using form submit, or an angular HTTP request to submit the form data?

Comment: Edit - yes - would like to let users paste CSV data - list of last and first names themselves separated by lets say semi colon - for eg., Gates, Bill; Jobs, Steve; Zuckerberg, Mark. I would like to submit using a $HTTP post but am open to any other method if that will help.

Answer (score 0):

Use ng-pattern with a regex in your field.

Lets say your field are number positive with comma separated value, and you can have one to many.

The regex would be : \d+((,\d)*).